# Onsen UI pull hook throws error when used in tabbar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui

I am using the pull hook component on a page that contains a ons-list element. This page is one of three (also list pages) that I use the tabbar component to navigate between. I only use the pull hook on the one page.

When switching pages (via the tabbar component) an error gets thrown:

"Error: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'element.off(:scroll",this._bindedOnScroll)')_destroyEventListeners@www/components/loader.js:1440:53691
_destroy@www/components/loader.js:1440:53771"

Can the pull hook component be used with the tabbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error happens when the pull hook is unloaded. It's an issue in the destructor.

If you make the tab "persistent" you won't experience the issue since it won't unload the pull hook:

```
<ons-tab persistent>
```

The error has been fixed in the latest beta version of Onsen UI (1.3.0-beta). You can install it with "bower install onsenui#1.3.0-beta" or you can wait for the 1.3.0 release which is due in a couple of days.